# Does Jekyll not watch Sass files in editing?

Tags: sass, less, jekyll

I did a standard installation of Jekyll and when I edit a .html file (or other markup accepted by Jekyll) the .scss files are compiled and copied to the _site directory correctly.

However, when I edit just the .scss file directly, Jekyll doesn't generate compiles again, I always need to go back to an .html file and save again.

I'm running the server with `bundle exec jekyll serve --livereload` normally.

This is as expected? is there any way for Jekyll to watch for edits to .scss files without me needing to add a Gulp for this?

PS.: My _config.yml has no relevant parameters.

Directory:

```
_layouts   
   default.md    
_posts   
_sass   
_site 
assets
   css
      style.scss   
index.md
```

Answer (score 0):

What version of Jekyll are you on? I seem to have Jekyll 4.0.1 installed locally and I can see it recompile when I edit a SCSS file.

I'm on Windows, and my Gemfile has:

`gem "jekyll", "~> 4.0.0"`

Comment: Im using Jekyll 4.3.2. Tried 4.0.1, but this continue not recompiling. Using on a Ubuntu via WSL2. It is important to emphasize that I am waiting for recompilation when I save the .scss file directly.